# How to play super high G on alto sax

Tags: fingering, saxophone

Is it possible to play the G6 on an alto saxophone?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does one play altissimo notes on an alto sax? specifically embouchure](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/52806/how-does-one-play-altissimo-notes-on-an-alto-sax-specifically-embouchure)

Comment: It's also possible to play the G one octave higher.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is most definitely possible. These are called *altissimo* notes. A very thorough resource for woodwind fingerings is the [Woodwind Fingering Guide](https://www.wfg.woodwind.org/).

However, to play these pitches, you need to do a lot more than just put down the fingers and blow (which you can get away with for all of the "normal" notes). You need to *voice* the notes correctly, which means using the shape of your mouth, throat, and the position of your tongue to support the correct overtone. Otherwise you'll get some kind of out-of-tune honk in the lower register, or some uncontrolled squeak. Practicing playing overtones of your lowest notes is a good preparatory exercise for playing altissimo.